# Как в listview выводить записи в шахматном порядке?

Tags: java, android, listview

У меня стоит задача: нужно отобразить название на русском, на английском и картинку. Всё это нужно выводить в активити, обычный listview помещает весь список вертикально, т.е:
Запись 1
Запись 2
Запись 3

А мне нужно чтобы выводилось как скрине, и горизонтально и вертикально: http://joxi.ru/5md0VDnIklZaYm

Как это сделать с помощью listview? или любой другой библиотеки, главное чтобы это было не сложно, так как я еще новичок. Буду рад ссылкам на материалы где можно изучить как это делается

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `RecyclerView` и `GridLayoutManager`

[Пример 1](http://www.journaldev.com/13792/android-gridlayoutmanager-example)

[Пример 2](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/)

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать

Comment: Спасибо тебе, Человек! Это оказалось именно то, что мне нужно!

Answer (score -1):

Лучше используйте LinearLayout. Вот вам необходимый код активити:

```
package com.cards.my.lingvicards;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Test extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        //вызывайте следующий метод, столько, сколько нужно создать дополнений указывая все необходимые параметры
        layout.addView(createChild("Русский текст", "Английский текст", R.id.your_drawable_resours));

    }

    private LinearLayout createChild(String rus , String eng , int res /*ссылка на ресурс в drawable*/ ){

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        TextView rusText = new TextView(this);
        rusText.setText(rus); //русский текст
        layout.addView(rusText);

        TextView engText = new TextView(this);
        engText.setText(eng); //английский текст
        layout.addView(rusText);

        ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
        image.setImageResource(res);
        layout.addView(rusText);

        return layout;
    }
}
```

Если есть вопросы по коду, то спрашивайте, отвечу.

Comment: Разве этот способ подойдет? Я ведь буду парсить JSON с сайта, а потом их класть в SQlite и выводить их списком в активити